# xargs echo colored output

Tags: terminal, xargs

I have the following command:

```
somethingRegex | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo -e "found \e[34m{}\e[39m";dummy {}'
```

The color part of the echo does not work, example output:

```
-e found \e[34mresult\e[39m
dummy output
repeat
```

A plain echo does work with *{}* being nice blue

```
echo -e "found \e[34m{}\e[39m"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is for Linux (although OSX adds an interesting twist by reversing the roles of `bash` and `echo`).

Linux's [`/bin/echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) has a `-e` option which expands escapes of the sort you show, while some shells (such as `dash`, used in Debian) follow [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) more closely, and do not do this.  The `find` program acts as if it runs `/bin/sh`, which may not be your actual shell.  Debian uses `dash` as `/bin/sh`.

Likewise, older versions of bash (my local OSX server has 3.2.53) do not support the `-e` option, while newer ones (checking my local Debian with 4.1.5) do support the `-e` option.

Since all of that behavior is non-standard, the usual recommendation is to use the [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) utility, which also provides non-standard features on Linux, but the parts that you *need* will be portable enough:

```
somethingRegex | xargs -I {} sh -c 'printf "found \033[34m{}\033[39m";dummy {}'
```